# The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400)

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have a web application which uses a WCF service. I'm trying to update something in a Database stored in cloud via this WCF service but I'm getting this error:

The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400)

I think that no matter how big would be maxRequestLenght and the other parameteres I will get StackOverFlow.

Here is some code:

WCF method to update an entry:

```
  public void updateMember(Membership member)
    {
        _context.Memberships.ApplyCurrentValues(member);
        _context.SaveChanges();     
    }
```

Edit method where I use the WCF Service:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Membership member)
    {
        Guid guid = AcsPrincipal.getGuid();
        Membership model = client.getMember(guid);
        model.Bikes = member.Bikes;
        model.City = member.City;
        model.Comment = member.Comment;
        model.Country = member.Country;
        model.Age = member.Age;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            client.updateMember(model);
            return RedirectToAction("Details");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

I'm stuck here for a couple of days...

Thanks a lot!

Later edit
WCF web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel"
          switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
          propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="traceListener"
          type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData= "c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
</system.diagnostics>
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="Off" />
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies> 
<add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </assemblies>
 </compilation>
 </system.web>
 <system.serviceModel>
 <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
  </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
<serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior>
    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
  </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

Web app config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
-->
<configuration>
<configSections>
<section name="microsoft.identityModel" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Configuration.MicrosoftIdentityModelSection, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
</configSections>
<system.diagnostics>
<trace>
  <listeners>
    <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics">
      <filter type="" />
    </add>
  </listeners>
</trace>
</system.diagnostics>
<appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="FederationMetadataLocation" value=" https://exciteaccesscontrol.accesscontrol.windows.net/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml " />
</appSettings>
<location path="FederationMetadata">
<system.web>

  <authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
<system.web>
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
<authentication mode="None" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<!--Commented out by FedUtil-->
<!--<authentication mode="Forms"><forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" /></authentication>-->
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <!--<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />-->
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <!--<add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />-->
    <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <!--<add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />-->
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
<!--
        If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
        you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
        change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
        of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
  -->
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
<httpModules>
  <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
</httpModules>
</system.web>
<system.net>
<settings>
  <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" />
</settings>
</system.net>
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
</system.webServer>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
<microsoft.identityModel>
<service>
  <audienceUris>
    <add value="http://localhost:28547/" />
  </audienceUris>
  <federatedAuthentication>
    <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://exciteaccesscontrol.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/wsfederation" realm="http://localhost:28547/" requireHttps="false" />
    <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
  </federatedAuthentication>
  <applicationService>
    <claimTypeRequired>
      <!--Following are the claims offered by STS 'https://exciteaccesscontrol.accesscontrol.windows.net/'. Add or uncomment claims that you require by your application and then update the federation metadata of this application.-->
      <claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" optional="true" />
      <claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" optional="true" />
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier" optional="true" />-->
      <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider" optional="true" />-->
    </claimTypeRequired>
  </applicationService>
  <issuerNameRegistry type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
    <trustedIssuers>
      <add thumbprint="363D1B4E8CF16B68C674B0FABEB7A692B52152C0" name="https://exciteaccesscontrol.accesscontrol.windows.net/" />
    </trustedIssuers>
  </issuerNameRegistry>
  <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
 </service>
</microsoft.identityModel>
<system.serviceModel>

<behaviors>

  <endpointBehaviors>

    <behavior name="maxItemsInObjectGraphBehaviour">

      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />

    </behavior>

  </endpointBehaviors>

</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" allowCookies="true"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="500000000"
             maxBufferSize="500000000"
             maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<client>
  <endpoint address="http://excitewcf.cloudapp.net/Service1.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
    contract="Service.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" behaviorConfiguration="maxItemsInObjectGraphBehaviour" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E400.html

Comment: Try enabling tracing at the server side, that can give you some additional information on why the request is being considered to be bad.

Comment: The WCF is published in Azure, I tried to connect with remote desktop, but I can't get the logs. Tomorrow I try to host the WCF service on localhost and get the logs.

Comment: How you get the "Client" proxy object?

Comment: @Erik Fan I get the client proxy object like this :        Service1Client client = new Service1Client(); you can check that here : http://excitewcf.cloudapp.net/Service1.svc

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after 2 days I figured it out!

The problem was:

_context.Memberships.ApplyCurrentValues(member);

Now I'm updating the model before, and just saving the changes in the WCF.